# How to build RPM for fedora/RH and DEB for debian/ubuntu with cpack on one machine

Tags: cmake, rpm, deb, pkg-config, cpack

I want to generate .deb and .rpm packages from multiple CMake C++ projects with CPack.
This works, if i build .deb packages on debian and .rpm packages on Fedora. But if i build them cross-distro, they get the paths wrong.

Have a look at one of my libraries where i tried to set this up: https://github.com/tfc/pprintpp

My workflow is:

```sh
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr <src>
make
cpack -G DEB/RPM
```

The package contains:

- headers
- pkg-config file
- cmake config file

When pkg-config and cmake are installed, they usually come with tools-specific search paths that are set distro-specific

If i use DEB on Fedora, the package installs libraries and pkgconfig/cmake files in `/usr/lib64/...` whereas cmake and pkg-config are configured to expect them in `/usr/lib/<pkgconfig/cmake>`.

If i use RPM on Debian, the package installs them in `/usr/lib/...` which is where Fedora doesn't look for them.

I need some way to generate such packages from one single distro, ideally even any distro.

Is there a way to instruct CMake and/or CPack to "do it right" without hardcoding too many things into my cmake files or calls?

Comment: Generally, a CMake project (after building and possibly installing it) can only be used on a machine where it is configured. Or on the machine with the same layout of files. Since Fedora and Debian has different files layout, the project configured on Fedora cannot be used on Debian and vice versa. And even if you have two versions of Fedora with different files layout, the project configured for one of them cannot be used on another one. CPack cannot resolve these incompatibilities: it simply packs files, installed (virtually) on one machine for being able unpack these files on other machine.

Comment: Note also, that aside from the files` layout, different distros may have **incompatible libraries**, or use **incompatible naming scheme** for them. So even if you "fix" layout of files, you would unable to use your project's library/executable on other machine. Generally, if you want to build the project on one machine and use it on another machine, you need to **cross-compile**.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware that my approach would be problematic with compiled libraries, so i am already preparing my CI to build in distro-specific containers/VMs.

I did however hope that this would not be necessary for header-only packages.

Comment: Many CMake projects use [GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/GNUInstallDirs.html) CMake module for set standard install directories *per component*: executables, libraries, headers, etc. Exactly this module is responsible for distinguish files layout scheme used on one distro from another. This is done by **inspecting the current machine**. E.g. the module [checks existence](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/GNUInstallDirs.cmake#L226) of `/etc/debian_version` file. It would be difficult to "fake" this check.